How to create a Context Manager Wrapper for class-based Context Managers?
I have two larger classes, which represent a resource, i.e., both are actual hardware that is connect to the PC. The two devices are not the same.
Both classes implement context managers.
The resources need to the passed to functions. The code can be simplified as follows:
def my_fun_0(resource_a, resource_b):
    print(resource_a, resource_b)

def my_fun_1(resource_a):
    print(resource_a)

def my_fun_2(resource_a, resource_b):
    print(resource_a, resource_b)


class A:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def __enter__(self):
        return self
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb):
        return True
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return "A"

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def __enter__(self):
        return self
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb):
        return True
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return "B"

The the application code looks something like this:
with A() as a, B() as b:
    my_fun_0(a, b)
    my_fun_1(a)
    my_fun_2(a, b)

Of course the actual application code is far more complex, i.e., it has more resources and more called functions, and I would like to omit passing all the context managers around.
So, I would like to be able to do something like this:
with C(A(), B()) as c:
    my_fun_0(c)
    my_fun_1(c)
    my_fun_2(c)

I know, that I can implement it like this, but my guts tell me, that this is not a good solution:
def my_fun_0(c):
    print(c.a, c.b)

def my_fun_1(c):
    print(c.a)

def my_fun_2(c):
    print(c.a, c.b)


# class A and B as above

class C:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a: A = a
        self.b: B = b
    def __enter__(self):
        self.a = self.a.__enter__()
        self.a = self.b.__enter__()
        return self
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb):
        self.a = self.a.__exit__(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb)
        self.a = self.b.__exit__(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb)
        return True
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return "C"

with C(A(), B()) as c:
    my_fun_0(c)
    my_fun_1(c)
    my_fun_2(c)

The question is therefore, what is the correct way to implement __enter__ and __exit__ in this use case?
